# Python ffn combine performance stats

Tags: python, pandas

I have a few `timeseries` created using `pandas` which I would like to calculate the stats for:

```
        ts = NAV.objects.get_adj_nav(fund_id)['adj_nav']
        ts.name = Fund.objects.get(id=fund_id).account_class_description
        ts = ts.to_frame()
        cols_to_datetime(ts,'index')
        ts_df = ffn.core.calc_stats(ts).to_csv(sep=',')

        print(ts_df)
```

So this is just one iteration of the loop and `ts_df` produces something like this:

```
Stat,CLASS F
Start,2013-09-03
End,2017-08-18
Risk-free rate,0.00%
,,,,,,,,,,,
Total Return,50.27%
Daily Sharpe,1.13
Daily Sortino,1.54
CAGR,10.84%
Max Drawdown,-11.06%
Calmar Ratio,0.98
```

So for each of the `timeseries` this will get generated with different `values` but the labels (e.g "First Column") will be the same. So I am just wondering how I can combine the different `ts_df` to produce one big `csv` object?

EDIT: For example, the output would be something like this:

```
Stat,CLASS F, CLASS G
Start,2013-09-03, 2013-09-07
End,2017-08-18, 2017-08-28
Risk-free rate,0.00%, 0.01%
,,,,,,,,,,,
Total Return,50.27%, 51.27%
Daily Sharpe,1.13, 1.16
Daily Sortino,1.54, 1.77
CAGR,10.84%, 11.7%
Max Drawdown,-11.06%, -9.7%
Calmar Ratio,0.98, 0.88
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking but you can append to a csv by chaning the `mode` paramter of `to_csv` to 'a'

Comment: @TedPetrou  Sorry, I added what the solution should look like

Comment: What are those commas? They don't match the number of columns.

Comment: @TedPetrou They are like a newline, but we can ignore them

Comment: Just save each iteration as an element to a list and then just run `pd.concat`

Comment: But I don't want the first column label to show up more than once.

Comment: @TedPetrou and you can't concat a non-NDFrame object

Comment: What are these objects?

Comment: performaceStats objects http://pmorissette.github.io/ffn/ffn.html